# In what order should the Aquarion series be watched?

Tags: aquarion

I heard that Aquarion exists/*Aquarion Logos* is running. If I were to watch all the related series in full, including *Aquarion Genesis*, *Aquarion Evol*, etc., where should I start and what order should I watch them all in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that *Aquarion* is an original anime (i.e. not based from other sources), it's safe to say that **the original broadcast time is the recommended order**:

1. [*Genesis of Aquarion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_Aquarion) (July 2005, 26 episodes): the original story
2. [*Genesis of Aquarion* OVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_Aquarion_(OVA)) (May & November 2007, 2 episodes) / [*Genesis of Aquarion: Wings of Genesis* movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_Aquarion_(OVA)) (September 2007): an alternative retelling of *Genesis of Aquarion*
3. [*Aquarion Evol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarion_Evol) (January 2012, 26 episodes): takes place 12000 years after *Genesis of Aquarion*
4. [*Genesis of Aquarion Evol* / *Genesis of Aquarion Love* OVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarion_Evol#OVA) (July 2015, 1 episode): featuring a crossover between characters from *Genesis of Aquarion* and *Aquarion Evol*
5. [*Aquarion Logos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarion_Logos) (July 2015, 26 episodes): featuring a new storyline unrelated to the previous 2 series.